# Difference between two stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have two SQL Stored Procedure. One from test environment and other is on the production. I have to check that whether there is any change in the stored procedure on the production environment.

Is their any way I can find the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) from Red Gate

Answer (score 1):

Many Database compare tools exist out there like [red-gate's sql compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)

Answer (score 1):

Comparing SPs is easy: you can use the [`sys.procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) view and the [`object_definition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) function get the SP source and compare this.

You can of course also use any tool which is able to script and/or compare database objects.

The open-source [bsn ModuleStore database versioning toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/) can also compare this for you at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Adept SQL Diff](http://www.adeptsql.com/) for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 (and possibly 2005, not sure) has a database schema compare tool, although I think it's only included in the database edition of the IDE.